# Plotting a heatmap with different bin sizes in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that I would like to plot as a heatmap. There are 3 columns: x, y, and the count at point (x,y). The problem is that the bins have different sizes in y (and not in x), for example

```
-0.3    0       0
-0.3    6.7082  0
-0.3    8.66025 0
-0.3    10.247  0
-0.3    11.619  0
-0.3    12.8452 0
...
```

But when I plot using for example

```
set view map
set size ratio -1
set key off
splot "histo.txt" u 1:2:3 w image
```

I get an image in which the bin sizes in the y direction are the same, thus the picture is distorted.
How can I plot a heatmap with different bin sizes in one direction? I also know exactly where each bin should begin and end in y, the values in the second column of the data file are a weigthed average.

Thank you.

Comment: `with image` plots a pixel image, with a regular pixel grid. Try `pm3d`, and read the docs for `pm3d interpolate` and `pm3d corners2color` to understand how that works.

Comment: Thank you, that worked (after fixing the blank lines in the data file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot offers basically two plotting styles suitable for heat maps, `pm3d` and `image`, which however have very different behaviour:

**`image`**:

- Draws a pixel image
- Always uses a regular grid, no matter what x or y values are used
- Each quadrangle (here, the pixel) is centered on one data point

**`pm3d`**:

- Draws vectorial quadrangles
- Can use irregular grids with varying spacings
- Draws each quadrangle with four data points as corners. The color is by default given by the mean value of those four points, that can be changed with `set pm3d corners2color ...`
- Can interpolate
- Many more features, applicable for 3d etc

So, to summarize: `image` can be used for heat maps and has its advantages, but in your case you need `pm3d`, which offers you the flexibility, you need.